# Apache CXF - Rest URL Parameters encoding

Tags: java, rest, urlencode, cxfrs

I am using `CXF - Rest` service.

```
@GET
@Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})
@Path("/search/")
R findUser(@QueryParam("email") String email);
```

I am invoking the `GET` call from `Postman` or `cURL`, something like this

```
http://localhost:8080/rest-service/search/?email=test+1@gmail.com
```

But when I debug the `email` field, I am getting the data field as `test 1@gmail.com`. I guess somewhere URL decoding is happening and because of that `+` is getting disappeared? How do I configure CXF/service to `not to alter` the URL parameters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the `@Encoded` annotation to your method which will disable the automatic decoding of parameters. See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/index.html?javax/ws/rs/Path.html)

> Disables automatic decoding of parameter values bound using
>   QueryParam, PathParam, FormParam or MatrixParam. Using this annotation
>   on a method will disable decoding for all parameters. Using this
>   annotation on a class will disable decoding for all parameters of all
>   methods.